# TextBox_Click event is not working for .net framework 3.5 with visual studio 2008

Tags: c#

TextBox_Click event is not working  for .net framework 3.5 with visual studio 2008.

It gives the error  **No overload for textbox_Click matches delegate System.EventHandler.**

**Can you please help me on this.If not ,Is there any alternative to Text_Click.**

And also what is the difference between TextBox_Click ,TextBox_Select, TextBox_GotFocus.

```
private void pinInput_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //If already there is a text inside text box--set that textbox to empty so that user can enter another pin.
}
```

The error is shown in Designer.cs at the line:
**`this.pinInput.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pinInput_Click);`**

And the method called for the event is

```
private void pinInput_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //If already there is a text inside text box--set that textbox to empty so that user can enter another pin.
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code of your textbox_Click. And also explain what do you want to do on a click over a textbox.

Comment: Pls Show code otherwise do not expect any answer.

Comment: private void pinInput_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        { If already there is a text inside text box--set that textbox to empty so that user can enter another pin.}

Comment: There is no KeyEventArgs for a click event. it should just be `EventArgs` @shinchan

Comment: Show your code inside the question section. not as a comment

Comment: The textbox event handler for a Click event doesn't expect to receive a KeyEventArgs (there is no key pressed in that event) but a simple EventArgs. Did you write that event manually or copy/pasted a previous event handler?

Comment: In designer.cs i have given the event as --------this.pinInput.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pinInput_Click);   At this line the error is shown.

Comment: I copy pasted because for the same text box there is another handler named keyDown.But only changed name of the event.

Comment: thanks all,ill try with eventargs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
private void pinInput_Click(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //If already there is a text inside text box--set that textbox to empty so that user can enter another pin.
}
```

To

```
private void pinInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    //If already there is a text inside text box--set that textbox to empty so that user can enter another pin.
}
```